# Wrapping chained method calls on a separate line in Emacs for Javascript

Tags: javascript, emacs

I haven't been successful in figuring out how to wrap each method call in Emacs. For example, if I have this:

someObject.a().b().c();

I really want this:

```
someObject.a()
          .b()
          .c();
```

Is this possible in Emacs? I've seen the same topic covered for Eclipse, but nothing in Emacs that i could find.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I'm thinking of is to search and replace. I propose a solution, but it is missing correct indentation right now.

Manually, call `M-%` (or `M-x query-replace`) and ask to replace `).` by `)^Q^J.` (the trick is here: to insert a newline in the prompt, enter `C-q` and then `C-j`).

If we wrap this to a callable function:

```
(defun my-js-wrap-method-calls ()
     (interactive)
     (setq beg (line-beginning-position))
     (setq end (line-end-position))
     (save-restriction
       (narrow-to-region beg end)
       (beginning-of-line)
       (replace-string ")." ")
    .")
     )
     )
```

It applies on the current line.
but as I say I'm looking how to indent the things correctly.

ps: elisp help: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Emacs_Lisp_Cheat_Sheet#Positions & http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_basics.html & http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Emacs_Lisp_Cookbook

Answer (score -1):

The indentation that you want isn't the default one in `js2-mode`.

This function will stack the call chain and indent it according to your mode:

```lisp
(defun javascript-chain-stack ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (if (looking-at ".*?\\sw+\\.\\sw+(.*;$")
      (let* ((str (match-string-no-properties 0))
             (beg (match-beginning 0))
             (end (match-end 0))
             (strs (split-string str "\\." t))
             (rstr (concat (car strs)
                           (mapconcat
                            (lambda (x) (concat "." x))
                            (cdr strs) "\n"))))
        (delete-region beg end)
        (insert rstr)
        (indent-region beg (+ beg (length rstr))))
    (error "Couldn't match JavaScript chain call")))
```

This will be the result (in my indentation setup):

```
someObject.a()
  .b()
  .c();
```

The function can be called from anywhere on the line.